# hive - sum & max within date group

Tags: hive

I want to use sum and max depending on date value : 
I have table 1:

```
Cal_day |   Date2 | value |
20160505|   20160505|   50 |
20160505|   20160505|   15|
20160505|   20160507|   1|
20160505|   20160507|   3|
20160505|   20160508|   2|
```

Output :
Depending on the date2 , in this case there are 2 entries on 20160505 (1st date2 so I would order by and get this sorted) so I need a max from it if i have more than 1 entry and then sum of all remaining values for date2. 
Final answer is for value on cal day 20160505 = max(50,15) + sum(1,3,2) = 56

How can I achieve this in Hive ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is completely un-answerable.  How are you deciding to take the max of the first two values and sum the other ones?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for pointing out. Yes I forgot to give the selection / deciding logic. I have now edited my question. Logic is  (a). Take the max of value on the first date2
(b). Take the sum of all other values for other date2

Comment: is not clear why you want to order by date 2.  can you provide a specific example?

Comment: When a correction to value is done then entry is made with date2 keeping cal_day same.  Value on cal_day is the actual value and all the other are mere correction n small hence i need max on 1st entry and rest as sum.